# Python delete entry from dictionary by value

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to delete unwanted entries from a dictionary. The dictionary looks like:

```
 {  "Id":101119     ,"entry1":50009987  ,"entry2":8     ,"entry3":4 }
```

and my code is:

```
import json

value = 2

with open(path, 'r') as json_input:
    unfiltered = json.load(json_input)

for row in unfiltered:
    id = row['Id']
    if row[field] is None:
        del output[id]
    elif int(row[field]) != value:
        del output[id]
```

However, I've got an error:

> KeyError: 101119

How can I fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: So where are you setting `value`?

Comment: Well, "101119" is not a key in your dictionary.

Comment: Where does `field` get a value? It might just be the wrong type (`101119` or `'101119'`?). (Also, it's not clear which `dict` is throwing the error, `row` or `output`.)

Comment: And you are deleting from `output`; what is `output` here? That dictionary has no such key `101119`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete a key-value pair from a dictionary if you only know its value. One possible alternative is to create a new dictionary from the old one, filtering out the values you don't want. Example:

```
d = {4: 8, 15: 16, 23: 42, 99: 8}
d = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if value != 8}
print(d)
```

Result:

```
{15: 16, 23: 42}
```

I don't 100% understand your code sample, but I expect you could do:

```
output = {key: value for key, value in output.items() if value != id}
```

Comment: You can delete the _first_ key with that value, or _every_ key with that value (like the way string operations typically work). Point being that keys are unique, but values are not (necessarily).